# Google play supported devices 0 with pdfbox-android

Tags: java, android, pdfbox

Have a problem with an already-published application on Google Play.

The application is in the store, but no one can download, because of an error `Supported devices 0`.

I did refactor the project, removed all unnecessary with the manifest. Compiled a new apk, and again "Supported devices 0".

I use pdfbox-android-1.8.8.jar.

If I remove the pdfbox from project, then are "Supported devices 7700".

I build project with Eclipse.

What does this mean?

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.firm.project"
   android:versionCode="3"
   android:versionName="1.01" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>

 <uses-permission   android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

 <application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".StartActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"  
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".OneActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

  </application>

 </manifest>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the `<uses-*>` and `<supports-*>` entries from your manifest? Those include `<uses-permission>`, `<uses-feature>` and others.

Comment: Maybe the merge with the PDF library's manifest causes a problem. At a first glance the minimum SDK level of PdfBox is 19 (and not 15 as you specify in your manifest): https://github.com/Birdbrain2/PdfBox-Android/blob/master/library/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml ... Btw there seems to be an updated version of the library. Have you tried it?

Comment: I added sources files and delete .jar. This solved my problem.